# Reload listview when returning to fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments

I have a class that extends `ActionBarActivity` to handle my fragments.

I'm creating one fragment: This fragment inflates a layout with some `TextViews`, `EditText`, a `Button` and a `ListView`. Depending of the input the user inserts on the `EditText` and after he presses the `Button` a query is performed and the `ListView` is populated using an adapter that extends  `ArrayAdapter<String[]>`.

On that list, `onItemSelected`, a new fragment is created and `addToBackStack(null)` it's added right before the transaction is committed. Info is presented in the new fragment and when the user presses the back button, the fragment with the `listview` is shown. All items appear as before except the `listview`that it's not populated.

I have this:

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (operation == 2) {
            if (search.listContent != null) {
                //search.inputQuery.setText("x");
                search.arrayListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                search.listContent.invalidateViews();
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried to notify the adapter that changes are made and also tried to `invalidateViews` but the information is not shown.

If I try to debug `search` I can see that the listview (`listcontent`) is there and the `adapter`is set. I can even see the content of the adapter, that is, the data that was previously shown in the `listview`.

How can I reload my `listview`

```
static ArrayList<String[]> allData = new ArrayList<String[]>();
...
bD.open();
Cursor query = null;
// perform query
query.moveToFirst();
for (int j = 0; j < query.getCount(); j++) {
    String[] fData = new String[]{"idNumber", "des", "source", "bd"};
    fData[0] = String.valueOf(query.getInt(0));
    fData[1] = query.getString(1);
    fData[2] = getSource(query.getInt(2), i + 1);
    fData[3] = String.valueOf(i + 1);
    allData.add(fData);
    query.moveToNext();
}
bD.close();
```

Comment: the code where you fill your adapter's item should be in the `onResume()` method too .

Comment: I've tryed also `search.listContent.setAdapter(search.arrayListAdapter);` (this only) but with no luck

Comment: you have to add the new data to the adapter in OnResume.

Comment: @Favolas : you should get the data and setted to your adapter before calling the notifyDataSetChanged(), add the code where you are instanciating your adapter

Comment: @Houcine,Justin like this? `search.listContent.setAdapter(search.arrayListAdapter);
search.arrayListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` On the class  I'm setting the adapter like this: `arrayListAdapter = new SearchAdapter(mContext, allData);listContent.setFastScrollEnabled(false); listContent.setAdapter(arrayListAdapter);`

Comment: it should be something like this : 
`//get allData somewhere and fill that array

arrayListAdapter = new SearchAdapter(mContext, allData); listContent.setAdapter(arrayListAdapter);`
or if the arrayListAdapter is not null , you can define a method to set the items and then call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: @Houcine This is what I've done but with no success:
            `if (search.listContent != null) {
                search.arrayListAdapter = new Search.SearchAdapter(search.mContext, search.allData);
                search.listContent.setAdapter(search.arrayListAdapter);
            }`

Comment: check the allData if it is not null , you should fill that array (allData) FIRST. Please edit your question and add the full code where you are getting your data and filling the allData array

Comment: allData is not null. If I debug I can see that it is still full with the data that was shown previously.

Comment: it's strange, the following code should work :

`if (search.listContent != null) {                 search.arrayListAdapter = new Search.SearchAdapter(search.mContext, search.allData);                 search.listContent.setAdapter(search.arrayListAdapter);             }`

Comment: @Houcine Yes. Very odd. I even tried to do `Search.SearchAdapter mySearchAdapter = (Search.SearchAdapter) search.listContent.getAdapter();
                mySearchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` but still the same